# Why Always navigate to Home Page View-ios

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, stack, xib, popviewcontroller

My app contain 5 xib
When i navigate to Home to 2nd View and BACK to Home is work fine
But From 3rd View and Tap for BACK its Every Time Push to Home View, I have Try this

```
-(IBAction)doBack
{
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

in .xib file added UIView and in that View add a UIButton .

- also Tried **pushViewControllerAnimatede:**
- and **popToviewController:  animated:**

I have Mac OSX 10.8.3 , IOS 6 , Xcode 4.5.2

I think some How Stack is not Maintain but dont know how ????

Comment: 5 xib with 5 different view controller or 5 xib with one viewcontroller reference ?

Comment: With one viewcontroller .

Comment: then its for all xib with same Viewcontroller so only one time push for diffrent diffrent xib with same base-class so that is always you pop at your single viewcontroller

Comment: plz put your code for getting better solution

Answer (score 0):

I have used different xibs for singleView controller and apply buttons on every xib to push and pop and it is working fine.My code is displayed below:--

```
- (IBAction)pushToFourth:(id)sender {
    SPTViewController *viewController=[[SPTViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)pushToThird:(id)sender {
    SPTViewController *viewController=[[SPTViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)pushtoSecond:(id)sender
{
    SPTViewController *viewController=[[SPTViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)poptofirst:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)poptosecond:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)poptothird:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Harculer ther 5 xib connect with singleViewcontroller there have not any secondViewcontroller.

Comment: Ok I understand, he has only one viewController then why he is using poptoViewController

Comment: he not using PopToviewcontroller he using right code but there are only one viewcontroller in stack so there always get back to homeviewcontroller :)

Comment: lets have a little discussion in chat

Comment: I have pushed secondView from firstView and thirdView from secondView